# how django access static files through nginx in distributed enviroment

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have two machines,one is **nginx**(ip:192.168.239.139) and the other is **django**(ip:192.168.239.140) where logic code actually are.They communicate with each other via **wsgi** .When request comes in,nginx forwards the request to django,this works fine,but static files such as images/js/css cant be loaded.I have tried to modify django settting.py over and over again but no help and I read a lot articles about this problems are all useless,because their servername are all 'localhost' in nginx.conf which means their static files are in the same machine within nginx server,but mine is separate.Additionally,regardless of nginx,i only ran `python manage.py runserver`,and static files are loaded correctly,here is my code below:

**nginx.conf:**

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    upstream realservers{
                server 192.168.239.140:8080;
                #server 192.168.239.138:8000;
    }
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        location / {
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass realservers;
        }
    }
}
```

**django setting.py:**

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS=(
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder'
)
#STATICFILES_DIRS = (
#       os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'../static/'),
#       '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework_swagger/static/rest_framework_swagger/',
#)

STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'/static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and my static directory is under root of my project same position with manage.py

So, can anyone help me to solve this?I will appreciate that!

Comment: Have you run `collectstatic`? Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-in-production) on approaches to getting your static files to the right server?

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes,I ran collectstatic,and still not work,according to the doc you mentioned,it said django doesnt serve static or media files unless you build a whatever server to serve it or any tools ,is it ?

Comment: Yes but you have such a server (ie nginx) and that doc talks in detail about how you might go about copying your files there.

Comment: did `192.168.239.140:8080` serving correctly?

Comment: @DanielRoseman  Because my nginx and django are separated,x.x.x.139 and x.x.x.140,should i ran collectstatic in 140 to move my static files into 139 and configure my nginx location /static/ {alias /path/to/my/static/} in 139 to serve the statics?or should i build another nginx in 140 to serve local statics?

Comment: Yes, the first option looks like the right solution.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am trying,and do you have any recommend tools for transport static files between different servers since fabric only support python 2.5-2.7?

Comment: @DanielRoseman  I have tried it out , it worked,thanks for ur help :)